# need to catch posted value back in dropdown

Tags: php, forms, email

```
<select name="ui3" oninput="load_ui('#ui3')" id="ui3" class="form-control" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["ui3"]) ? $_POST["ui3"] : ''; ?>">
    <option value="IEC 60137: 2017">IEC 60137: 2017</option>
    <option value="ANSI / IEEE C57.19.00/01">ANSI / IEEE C57.19.00/01</option>
    <option value="other">Others</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `post` value is equal to `dropdown` options, like this:

```
<select name="ui3" oninput="load_ui('#ui3')" id="ui3" class="form-control">
    <option value="IEC 60137: 2017" <?= isset($_POST["ui3"]) && $_POST["ui3"] == 'IEC 60137: 2017' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>IEC 60137: 2017</option>
    <option value="ANSI / IEEE C57.19.00/01" <?= isset($_POST["ui3"]) && $_POST["ui3"] == 'ANSI / IEEE C57.19.00/01' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>ANSI / IEEE C57.19.00/01</option>
    <option value="other" <?= isset($_POST["ui3"]) && $_POST["ui3"] == 'other' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Others</option>
</select>
```

Comment: <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" required data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="birthday" required readonly placeholder="Select Date of Birth *" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["birthday"]) ? $_POST["birthday"] : ''; ?>"/>
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                        </div>